# implementing filtering in a rest api with nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

hope you could help me here.
I have json stored in mongodb. This json contains data about phones such as model, price, img src. Having got GET request with parameters such as price in url, I'd like to compare it with data stored in db and return only objects which contain such results.
Below providing my current code (where Phone is a name of mongoose.model):

```
router.get("/:price", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const phone = await Phone.find(c => c.price === parseInt(req.params.price));
        if (!phone) res.status(404).send('The phone with the given price was not found');
        res.send(phone);
    } catch (e) {
        res.send('Error ' + e);
    }
})
```

I have to mention that rest part of code is working with no problem on ordinary get, post requests. So I suppose that problem is hiding in this part of code.
The error I've got in console:
node:events:368
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'price'). In Postman I have another one: MongooseError: Query was already executed: Phone.find({})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the JS `Array.find()` method with the MongoDB `find({})` method.
Change your `find` method to be like this:

```
Phone.find({ "price": parseInt(req.params.price) });
```

Assuming you have the `price` property in your `Phone` model, this will find all documents that `price` equals to `req.params.price`

Comment: It's working! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Happy I could help. If this answered your question please accept this answer.